# How to remove accession from the gene id in the data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

How to remove the accession and leave only the name of the gene in the data frame? For example in "gb|AAV85982.1|ARO:3000535|macB" I would like to keep only macB.

This is how my data frame looks like

```
gene                                 n       freq
gb|ADZ12699.1|ARO:3005091|RanA       21  7.1917808
gb|AAV85982.1|ARO:3000535|macB       19  6.5068493
gb|APB03214.1|ARO:3003980|tetA(58)   17  5.8219178
```

And I'd like to have something like this

```
gene       n       freq
RanA       21  7.1917808
macB       19  6.5068493
tetA(58)   17  5.8219178
```

I know about substr() function but I am not sure how to apply it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

With `sub`, regardless of number of `|`.

```
cbind(gene = sub(".*\\|", "", df$gene), df[, 2:3])
      gene  n     freq
1     RanA 21 7.191781
2     macB 19 6.506849
3 tetA(58) 17 5.821918
```

Or using `strsplit`. Needs gene in position 4.

```
cbind(gene = sapply(strsplit(df$gene, "\\|"), "[", 4), df[, 2:3])
      gene  n     freq
1     RanA 21 7.191781
2     macB 19 6.506849
3 tetA(58) 17 5.821918
```